# Can i schedule a quartz job which will be picked by a specific node/server?

Tags: quartz-scheduler, scheduler

I am working in quartz scheduler. We have cluster environment for scheduler, can i schedule a quartz job which will be picked by a specific node/server?

For example : I have 3 Node in cluster: Node1, Node2 and Node3 and have 2 Jobs, job1 and job2.

I want to  that every time i schedule job2, it will be picked by only Node2. For Job1 there is no restriction.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName=node1  in scheduler.properties file.At time of job scheduling, we can set SchedName in job detail and trigger as node1, quartz will pick node1 as server to run job.